# Autocomplete Brackets - Zerobrane

Tags: zerobrane

Does Zerobrane have an autocomplete-function for brackets? 
I dont like it to always do the close-bracket and I found nothing on the Internet

Answer (score 1):

There is [autodelimiter plugin](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/autodelimiter.lua) that does auto-insertion of delimiters (), {}, [], '', and "".